# XAMPP Tomcat not connecting

Tags: tomcat, xampp

I have already downloaded and used everything on the XAMPP control pad.  It was working fine for months and then suddenly it stopped working and Tomcat kept on shutting down and displaying this error:

```
1:08:32 PM  [Tomcat]    Error: Tomcat shutdown unexpectedly.
1:08:32 PM  [Tomcat]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing     dependencies, 
1:08:32 PM  [Tomcat]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:08:32 PM  [Tomcat]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:08:32 PM  [Tomcat]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:08:32 PM  [Tomcat]    If you need more help, copy and post this
1:08:32 PM  [Tomcat]    entire log window on the forums
```

Can someone please help me fix this. Thanks.

Comment: And that tells you to check those places. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes and it didn't say anything. A previous answer on this site told me to change the ports, but I did that and it still gave me the same error.